# Comments, notify multiple users

Tags: support, comments

Is there a way to comment reply to multiple users that have commented on the same question?
i.e. I would like to reply with the same comment to the people that posted a comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745204/aspdropdownlist-selectedvalues-in-multiple-selection-list/25746734#25746734) question.

Comment: As far as I know, your comment should always generate a notification for the previous user that commented on that post, and the author of the post. Aside from that, you can @tag another user.

Comment: You just have to leave multiple comments yourself, or my preferred way is normally to just do "@All" or "@JoeBloggs and others", since most of the times I reply it doesn't really matter whether or not they read it

Comment: Hm, I didn't get notified of @Sayse's response. Seems I was wrong

Comment: @Sayse Thanks, so "@All" should notify all users that left a comment if I understand correctly. Or it is just a way to address the comment to All but without notification?

Comment: @FeliceM - No it doesn't send any notifications, its just a caveat I've adopted as a way to demonstrate what my intensions are

Comment: @Sayse I suspected that however it is a good way. Thanks

Comment: **No, don't use `@All`.** There is no such thing, it just confuses people. The only purpose of an at sign is to generate a notification. If you aren't generating that notification, then do not use an at sign. Along the same times, avoid `@downvoter`, `@close voters`, and all that other nonsense I see occasionally.

Comment: I have to admit that it would be useful to notify more than one person, and it cuts down on the work done and space taken, especially if you have to notify three or more people.

Comment: What about replacing the "support" tag of this question by "feature-request"?

Answer (score 8):

According to [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

> - The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of
>   any new comment.
> - You can explicitly notify **one (1)** other user if they
>   have a current (non-deleted) comment on the post or their name appears
>   anywhere in the revision history (only those who have commented will
>   show up in the auto-complete dialog though). Also note that users who
>   have closed or reopened a question without a binding close vote (i.e.
>   without a gold tag badge or a moderator vote) cannot be notified, even
>   though their usernames will appear in the revision history.

So, at most, two people can be notified of a comment. The OP of the post to which the comment is attached, and one other person who has "participated" on that post (by commenting on or editing the post).

There are more details at that FAQ than anyone could possibly want to know.